# Dropzone fixed height with horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, css, thumbnails, dropzone.js

I'm not adept enough in advanced CSS or dropzone to know how to modify the template so any help is appreciated. I would like to create a fixed-width, single-row-height area for the dropzone thumbnails that scrolls left-to-right for showing any files currently in the dropzone uploader.

Any help is appreciated. FYI, I have already isolated the CSS styles that set the width: 50% and I'm assuming at least part of the work goes there.

Answer (score 2):

OK, with some banging on the keys like one of those infinite monkeys, I was able to figure it out:

first I added an additional class name to my dropzone container:

```
<div class="dropzone hzScroll" id="lpDropzone"></div>
```

Then I added a style definition above it:

```
<style>
    .dropzone .dz-preview.lp-preview {
        width: 150px;
    }
    .dropzone.hzScroll {
        width: 740px;
        overflow: auto;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I did a similar custom class in the template for the .lp-preview so I could over-ride the 50% as mentioned in the original question.